# what happend with close connection before set AutoCommit true

Tags: java, connection, release

```
    } finally {
        JDBCUtil.close(rs, ps, conn);
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

// is that right ? if like this, will it cause the problem connection can not be released??

```
        conn = JDBCUtil.generateConn();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        logger.info("commit false");

        RosDao.deleteZLIFNRRGT(jbxxbean.getNAME1(), conn);
        RosDao.deleteZBP_PROD_CAT(jbxxbean.getNAME1(), conn);
        RosDao.deleteZBP_PUR_CAT(jbxxbean.getNAME1(), conn);
```

// in one transaction more database dao, should I close conn in every dao??? or close conn in parent function ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a transaction is open, closing the connection will abort it without committing (rollback), and then close the connection as usual.

If you try to change the auto commit mode of a closed connection you will get an exception thrown.